# How would I group by all the fields except one so that I can remove duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query.

```
select trackingbatches.batchnumber, requireddate, jobno, frames.frame_id, frame_no, groupdesc, finishdesc, finish2desc, BOUGHTINFRAME, NAME, MAX(statustimestamp) from JOBQUOTEHEADER
right join trackingbatches on JOBQUOTEHEADER.header_id=trackingbatches.header_id
right join frames on trackingbatches.header_Id=frames.header_id
right join trackingstagesettings on trackingbatches.status=trackingstagesettings.stage_id
where requireddate between current_date-1 and current_date
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
ORDER BY JOBNO
```

However, I do not want to group by 'name'. I want it to select the latest 'statustimestamp' but as of now, it groups by name also so it gives me a row which is the same frame with all the same details but multiple occurrences of it in the factory. name refers to the stage of the frame in our factory.

| BATCHNUMBER | REQUIREDDATE | JOBNO | FRAME_ID | FRAME_NO | GROUPDESC | FINISHDESC | FINISH2DESC | BOUGHTINFRAME | NAME | STATUSTIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5079 | 01.09 | 5STAR1 | 1 | 1 | INT CASEMENT | STD WHITE | N/A | 0 | CUT | 16.08.2021 |
| 5079 | 01.09 | 5STAR1 | 1 | 1 | INT CASEMENT | STD WHITE | N/A | 0 | LOADED | 02.09.2021 |

So as you can see from the two records above. That is the same frame but i only want one instance of it to show in my results, the instance of the latest status of it which is the second one that is 'LOADED' as its status with the field called name. So i want the max status timestamp for the latest instance of the frame but because it groups by the field 'name' as well, i can't get just the latest instance by itself.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: *I do not want to group by 'name'.* Remove according part of the grouping expression, but add some aggregation (for example, MAX(), GROUP_CONCAT(), etc.) into the output list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rank on your current query (when you see duplicates) something like the following:

- Rank will create a row number for each row per batchnumber in the desc order for date
- Once the rank is created you can just filter = 1 to get the data per batchnumer in desc order based on statustimestamp
- This way you don't need to worry about `NAME` GROUP BY as it it will not be in the partition by clause of the ROW_NUMBER() [which is creating the rank based on just batchnumber -- you can adjust it by adding more columns if you need something else to aggregate by]

```
WITH data AS (

select trackingbatches.batchnumber, requireddate, jobno, frames.frame_id, frame_no, groupdesc, finishdesc, finish2desc, BOUGHTINFRAME, NAME, MAX(statustimestamp) from JOBQUOTEHEADER
right join trackingbatches on JOBQUOTEHEADER.header_id=trackingbatches.header_id
right join frames on trackingbatches.header_Id=frames.header_id
right join trackingstagesettings on trackingbatches.status=trackingstagesettings.stage_id
where requireddate between current_date-1 and current_date
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
ORDER BY JOBNO 

),
rank_data_by_date AS

SELECT 
* 
,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BATCHNUMBER ORDER BY STATUSTIMESTAMP DESC) AS RANK_
)

SELECT * FROM rank_data_by_date WHERE RANK_ = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i am a novice with sql, sorry for being an idiot but how would i format and write this with my own query?

Comment: @tohidshah so here the results that you have from you will  be the `*` here and then after that you will add the `RANK_` column

Comment: @tohidshah try the code now, i have adjusted